# Adjusting the console apliacation (trycatch and while loop)

Tags: c#, while-loop, logic, try-catch, console-application

So in this code I'm trying to make it so that if the user inputs a value that is out of the range it will display the message:

> Enter a valid input (between 1 and 2^53)

What it is doing at the moment is that when you input a letter the message appears, but when you input a number lower than 0, it just resets the loop and continues as if nothing happened.

```
//variables
double length, width, totalarea, totallength;
const double feet = 3.75;

//questions
Console.Title = "Double Glazing Window Calculator";
Console.WriteLine("Double Glazing Calculator\n");
bool InputFalse = false;

do
{
   try
   {
      do
      {
          Console.Write("Enter the height of the of the window in meteres ");           
          length = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.Write("Enter the width of the of the window in meteres ");
          width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());   
      } while (length < 1 || width < 1);

      //maths
      totalarea = length * width * 2;
      totallength = (length * 2 + width * 2) * feet;
      Console.WriteLine("The total area of the glass required in m^2 (to 2 decinmal places) is {0} ", totalarea.ToString("0.##"));

      Console.WriteLine("the total length of the wood required in feet (to 2 decimal places) is {0}", totallength.ToString("0.##"));             
   }
   catch
   {
      InputFalse = (true);
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid input (between 1 and 2^53)");
   }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching the exception from `double.Parse` it would be better to use [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx).  And since you only want values that are at least 1 you can use the fact that `double.TryParse` will set the `out` parameters to 0 when parsing fails.

```
double length = 0, width = 0;
const double feet = 3.75;

//questions
Console.Title = "Double Glazing Window Calculator";
Console.WriteLine("Double Glazing Calculator\n");

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the height of the of the window in meteres ");
    double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length);
    Console.Write("Enter the width of the of the window in meteres ");
    double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out width);

    if (length < 1 || width < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid input (between 1 and 2^53)");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

//maths
var totalarea = length * width * 2;
var totallength = (length * 2 + width * 2) * feet;
Console.WriteLine("The total area of the glass required in m^2 (to 2 decinmal places) is {0} ", totalarea.ToString("0.##"));

Console.WriteLine("the total length of the wood required in feet (to 2 decimal places) is {0}", totallength.ToString("0.##"));
```

You could even split this up into 2 `while` loops so it doesn't let them enter the width until they enter a valid length first.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a method for the input, this would make the code more readable and like @juharr recommended use `TryParse` to avoid the need for `try-catch` blocks.

Example:

```
double length = 0, 
       width = 0, 
       totalarea, 
       totallength;
const double feet = 3.75;

//questions
Console.Title = "Double Glazing Window Calculator";
Console.WriteLine("Double Glazing Calculator\n");
bool InputFalse = false;

while(true){
    GetAndVerifyInput(out length, "Enter the length of the of the window in meteres: ");
    GetAndVerifyInput(out width, "Enter the width of the of the window in meteres: ");

    //maths
    totalarea = length * width * 2;
    totallength = (length * 2 + width * 2) * feet;
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The total area of the glass required in m^2 (to 2 decimal places) is {0} ", totalarea.ToString("0.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("the total length of the wood required in feet (to 2 decimal places) is {0}", totallength.ToString("0.##"));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}


private void GetAndVerifyInput(out double result, string instruction) {
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(instruction);
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) && 
            result > 0 && 
            result < Math.Pow(2,53) + 1)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid input (between 1 and 2^53)");
     }
}
```